# html select tag saying required even if an option is selected

Tags: php, html

i got a drop down in my html form, even if i have selected an option from it it still says i should select an item in the list and when i remove the required attribute and submit, it does not enter the option i selected into the database.

here is my code

```
      <form style="margin-bottom: 5%;" method="POST" action="generate-invoive-results-service.php">

                   <?php 
                     $query="SELECT diagnosis FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%" . $_COOKIE['searchdisease'] . "%'";
                     $result= $con->query($query);
                    ?>  
                          <select required="true" id="nol" style="width: 40%; margin-left: -1%;" name="tdisease" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="medications" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-rel="chosen">
                            <option value="">Select Disease</option>
                             <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
                      <?php } ?> 
                         </select><br>
                <input class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 170px; margin-left: -7%; margin-top: -1%; margin-bottom: 1%; color: #000;" type="submit" name="insertData" value="Create Invoice"> 
  </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insertData']))
{
    $pred =$_POST['pre']; 
    $np =$_POST['nap']; 
    $sd10 =$_POST['tdisease'];
    $pr =$_POST['pric'];  
    $ivd =$_POST['invd'];
    $id =$_POST['user'];

      $insert_user="INSERT INTO invoices(id, icd10, nappi_code, prescription, price, invoice_date, pid) VALUES ('','$sd10', '$np' ,'$pred','$pr','$ivd','$id')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$insert_user))
    {  
        echo"<script>alert(' Invoice Details successfuly added to database')</script>";
        echo '<meta content="1;generate-invoive-results-service-add.php?id='.$id.'" http-equiv="refresh" />';// redirects user view page after 3    
    }else{  
        echo"<script>alert('Unknown error occured')</script>";   
  } 
}
?>
```

Comment: When you submit. Have you tried echoing out the value of tdisease? Since select allows multiple options, tdisease is going to be an array. It could be that you're trying to insert an array into a single field in the DB.

Comment: i ddn echo it out but i posted it to a variable, 

here is code:

<?php
if(isset($_POST['insertData']))
{
    $pred =$_POST['pre']; 
    $np =$_POST['nap']; 
    $sd10 =$_POST['tdisease'];
    $pr =$_POST['pric'];  
    $ivd =$_POST['invd'];
    $id =$_POST['user'];
 
      $insert_user="INSERT INTO invoices(id, icd10, nappi_code, prescription, price, invoice_date, pid) VALUES ('','$sd10', '$np' ,'$pred','$pr','$ivd','$id')";

Comment: Edit your question and add in the code in there in its own block. Also, it might be useful to have the form tag html to make sure you're using the right names.

Comment: okay, i will modify it

Comment: You see this `SELECT diagnosis FROM medications`? You did not select the `ICD10` column for your `<option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>">` that's why your code's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Although it should not make a difference, but you should note that you repeated:

```
required="true"
```

If you can show the HTML code generated from PHP, it may help solving the issue.

Comment: here is code:

<?php
if(isset($_POST['insertData']))
{
    $pred =$_POST['pre']; 
    $np =$_POST['nap']; 
    $sd10 =$_POST['tdisease'];
    $pr =$_POST['pric'];  
    $ivd =$_POST['invd'];
    $id =$_POST['user'];
 
      $insert_user="INSERT INTO invoices(id, icd10, nappi_code, prescription, price, invoice_date, pid) VALUES ('','$sd10', '$np' ,'$pred','$pr','$ivd','$id')";

Comment: the "HTML code" generated at client-side, not the PHP code

Comment: Morena, you can get the HTML code generated/rendered to the user via "Inspect element" or "View source" options from right-click menu (chrome).

The code included in your question is the source code of your php file and that's not what I meant.

Comment: I believe your problem is purely in HTML.